# call a shared method in a loaded dll using class name

Tags: vb.net

```
sample.vb
class sam
public shared sub hh()
Console.WriteLine("asasas")
end sub
end class

test.vb
Dim ass as Assembly  = Assembly.LoadFile("sample.dll")
```

Now, I want to call the shared method using the class name.How do i do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection is your friend. Add a `Imports System.Reflection` and try the following:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("sample.dll")
    Dim t_sam As Type = ass.GetType("sam")
    Dim hh_m As MethodInfo = t_sam.GetMethod("hh", BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static)
    hh_m.Invoke(Nothing, New Object() {})
End Sub
```